# How to make a exe for java programs w/ icon

Tags: java, icons, exe

I have made a nice little java file. I'm convinced that I have developed it to the maximum  I can code. So, I was thinking, Minecraft is in java, and it has an exe for it, not a shortcut to the jar(That's the way I do it...), so how would I make an exe for my program? Plus, I have an icon, I put it into the bin and ran the program, and it worked. Where would I put it now?

Comment: I'll add here this old question as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/147181/422353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Launch4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/), that's what I use to make an `.exe` out of my Java `.jar` installers.

Comment: Do you think that this is effective?

Comment: @user1766728 What do you mean "effective" - it certainly works and I've been using it successfully for years, it can even prompt the user to download Java if they try to run the `.exe` on a system that doesn't have a JRE installed.

Comment: I've used Launch4j on an application with about 200,000 users and growing.  My app includes a native lib (JOGL). No problems reported.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before and it isn't very effective. But here's a good place to start to figure it out for yourself: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Comment: what do you mean 'not effective'

Comment: Well, you can do it. But I found it to be cheesy because I take the stance which that article suggests that "You should not, because that would kill the very purpose of Java." I can't remember exactly what I did but you could literally write an executable in c which just calls the jar. I don't know exactly how Minecraft's exe works, but minecraft's exe does call a Jar. If you look under .minecraft/bin it's named minecraft.jar

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html), it's not free but it will do what you want.

Most executable of this nature are just some kind of wrapper that calls Java on your behalf.